# Pagination of Postgres dynamic query response of large data in microservice environment

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data

We are redesigning a legacy application which query large data using cursor and write each batch size data to file system after some processing. 
Now we are splitting this querying and processing into two Docker/kubernetes/Spring Boot based microservices and using Postgres as data source.

Our challenge is Pagination for large query response.We are concerned with using standard options like Skip(),Limit () due to performance reasons.Also our request query is dynamic for each request and response keys count can be from 1 to 1500 columns.And User can pass different sort order for requested columns keys(Col A asc, Col B Desc, Col C desc etc). so other suggested approaches like Keyset Pagination might not work.

We are looking for some suggestions like streaming of response so that as soon we get response of example 100 records our data service pass response to processor microservice and that service can write to file system.

Comment: You could use cursors, keep a database transaction open and fetch the result in batches rather than running multiple queries. That's what cursors are made for.

Comment: We can use cursors but challenge is in our request query we are asking different sorting for different requested columns , its dynamic query.so we are not sure for which key we make cursor .We would like to develop API response on top of cursor response as per below below Slack team approach. https://slack.engineering/evolving-api-pagination-at-slack-1c1f644f8e12

Comment: You don't need a key to create a cursor. Simply declare the cursor for your dynamic query, including the `ORDER BY` clause, and fetch the result in batches.